# Getting "Indexable is invalid" while inserting element into boost::geometry::index::rtree

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry, r-tree

I'm initializing my rtree with

```
namespace boostGEO = boost::geometry;
typedef boostGEO::model::point<double, 2, boostGEO::cs::cartesian> point;
typedef boostGEO::model::box<point> box;
typedef std::pair<box, std::pair<int, int>> edgesValue;
boostGEO::index::rtree< edgesValue, boostGEO::index::rstar<16> > tree();
```

And then i fill it like this

```
for( int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++ )
{
    Item* item = items.at(i);
    std::vector<ItemRelation> relations = item->getRelations();

    point ps1( item->x, item->y );
    Item* relatedItem;
    for( int j = 0; j < relations.size(); j++ )
    {
        relatedItem = relations.at(j);
        point ps2( relatedItem->x, relatedItem->y );
        box bounds( ps1, ps2 );
        edgesTree.insert( std::make_pair( bounds, std::make_pair(item->id, relatedItem->id) ) );
    }
}
```

Item->x and Item->y are doubles and Item->id is Integer.
When I run my code I am getting the following error:

```
/opt/bp/boost_1_58_0/boost/geometry/index/rtree.hpp:1248: void boost::geometry::index::rtree<Value, Options, IndexableGetter, EqualTo, Allocator>::raw_insert(const value_type&) [with Value = std::pair<boost::geometry::model::box<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2ul, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> >, std::pair<int, int> >; Parameters = boost::geometry::index::rstar<16ul>; IndexableGetter = boost::geometry::index::indexable<std::pair<boost::geometry::model::box<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2ul, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> >, std::pair<int, int> > >; EqualTo = boost::geometry::index::equal_to<std::pair<boost::geometry::model::box<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2ul, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> >, std::pair<int, int> > >; Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<boost::geometry::model::box<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2ul, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> >, std::pair<int, int> > >; boost::geometry::index::rtree<Value, Options, IndexableGetter, EqualTo, Allocator>::value_type = std::pair<boost::geometry::model::box<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2ul, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> >, std::pair<int, int> >]: Assertion `(detail::is_valid(m_members.translator()(value)))&&("Indexable is invalid")' failed.
```

Could anyone pls give me a hint what went wrong? I have totally no idea.

Comment: I can't make heads or tails out of this. Is an `ItemRelation` a subclass of `Item` now?

Comment: Oh, my mistake. ItemRelation=Item*, like you guessed in the code-example below. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The assertion failure informs you that bounds of a value you're trying to insert are invalid. That is that for some dimension Box's max coordinate is lesser than min coordinate. You may check it before inserting a new value into the rtree:

```
if (bg::get<0>(ps1) > bg::get<0>(ps2) || bg::get<1>(ps1) > bg::get<1>(ps2))
{
    std::cerr << "invalid bounds" << std::endl;
    continue;
}
```

For the future, you should learn how to debug your program. The debugger would stop in a place where the assertion fails. You could use the call stack to go into the `rtree::insert` call in the `main` function. Then you would be able to see what actually you're trying to insert into the rtree.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean

```
boostGEO::index::rtree<edgesValue, boostGEO::index::rstar<16> > tree;
```

(note the missing parens?). See also [Most vexing parse: why doesn't A a(()); work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work)

---

Beyond this I've seen no such problem:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9da41c5f6a3b8056)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometry.hpp>
#include <string>

using namespace boost;
namespace boostGEO = boost::geometry;
typedef boostGEO::model::point<double, 2, boostGEO::cs::cartesian> point;
typedef boostGEO::model::box<point> box;
typedef std::pair<box, std::pair<int, int> > edgesValue;

struct Item;
using ItemRelation = Item*;

struct Item {
    double x, y;
    int id;
    std::vector<ItemRelation> _rel;
    std::vector<ItemRelation> getRelations() const { return {}; }
};

int main() {
    Item item1  { 1, 2, 1, {} },
         item2  { 1, 4, 2, {} },
         item3  { 1, 6, 2, {} },
         item4  { 2, 1, 4, {} },
         item5  { 2, 3, 5, {} },
         item6  { 2, 5, 5, {} };

    std::vector<Item*> items { &item1, &item2, &item3, &item4, &item5, &item6, };

    item3._rel = { &item1, &item2 };
    item6._rel = { &item4, &item5 };

    boostGEO::index::rtree<edgesValue, boostGEO::index::rstar<16> > edgesTree;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
        Item *item = items.at(i);
        std::vector<ItemRelation> relations = item->getRelations();

        point ps1(item->x, item->y);
        Item *relatedItem;
        for (size_t j = 0; j < relations.size(); j++) {
            relatedItem = relations.at(j);
            point ps2(relatedItem->x, relatedItem->y);
            box bounds(ps1, ps2);
            edgesTree.insert(std::make_pair(bounds, std::make_pair(item->id, relatedItem->id)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It was not about the missing parens. I accidentally added them to my code-example. The Problem still persists.

Comment: The first item is inserted correctly. The error is happening while inserting the second.

Comment: @Lars the code shown runs. It's inserting 6 items. You can see it running live. Please use this to spot the relevant differences.